# hashcode use not showing in code

Tags: java, collections

I am learning about `hashcode()` method in java. I was going through the tutorials
and saw that hashcode() is mainly used in HashMap,HashTable and HashSet.
This is what I have understood,If we want to insert an object as an key, then we have to override hashcode().
Other it wont be able to lookup for the key. 
I did a small example and I could achieve this without overriding the hashCode.
So what is the exact use of hashCode() ?

See the code below

```
package hashcode;

public class Bucket {

    private int number;

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + number;
    }

}


package hashcode;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class MainHashcodeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hashtable<Bucket, String> map = new Hashtable<>();
        Bucket bucket = new Bucket();
        bucket.setNumber(100);
        map.put(bucket, "A");

        System.out.println(map.get(bucket));

    }
}
```

Comment: Override hashCode & equals method , print current thread  stack trace.It gives and idea, what is going on.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the exact same reference to your `Bucket`, so the default implementation of `.hashCode()` and `.equals()` are used (resp. [`System.identityHashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) and reference equality).

Now try and:

```
Set<Bucket> set = new HashSet<>();

// Create two buckets b1, b2 with the same number

set.add(b1); set.add(b2);
```

The set will have size 2. If `b1` and `b2` were equal (which they are not), the set would have had size 1.

Now, let us suppose that you implement `.equals()`, but not `.hashCode()`:

```
// no hashCode(), but...

@Override
// simplified
public boolean equals(@Nullable final Object obj)
{
    // instanceOf works with null, so this works
    if (!(obj instanceOf Bucket))
        return false;
    return ((Bucket) obj).number == number;
}
```

and you run the code above... The set *will still have size 2*. Why? Because `b1` and `b2` are not the same reference, and `Object`'s `.hashCode()` will (most probably) return a different result for both.

You therefore need to override *both* `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` for proper use. See the [javadoc of `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) for more details, the contract for both is explained at length.

Note also that `.hashCode()` has no "cryptographic value". This is a perfectly legal (albeit useless) implementation of it:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: yes. It is working fine after I overriden the equals and hashcode()method. so can we say hashcode is highly dependent on equals?

Comment: They are both intrinsically linked; again, the javadoc for Object explains it all, I cannot recommend enough that you read it thoroughly ;)